# Attach event handler to labels of an nvd3 chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to attach `click` event handler to `nvd3` `discreteBarchart`s' label on the x-axis. Here is the code:

```
labelClick = () => {
 console.log("label was clicked!!!");
}

drawBarChartWithData = (node, clusterData) => {
 console.log("drawBarchartWithData method called");
 var that = this;
   nv.addGraph(function() {
      var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
          .x(function(d) { return d.label })
          .y(function(d) { return d.value })
          .staggerLabels(true)
          //.staggerLabels(historicalBarChart[0].values.length > 8)
          .showValues(false)
          .duration(250)
          ;
      d3.select(node)
          .datum(clusterData)
          .call(chart);

--------> d3.select(node)
        .selectAll('.tick')
          .on('click', that.labelClick); <----------

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      return chart;
  }.bind(this));
}
```

The code above that is highlighted with arrows is how I am trying to add the handler. I also tried the same code outside of the `nv.addGraph` function and supplying the event handler function in line:

```
       d3.select(node)
        .selectAll('.tick')
          .on('click', function(d) {
            console.log(d + "label was clicked!!!");
          });
```

I tried also `.selectAll('text')` and `selectAll('.x.axis .tick')` instead of `.selectAll('.tick')`.

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NVD3 has default styles `pointer-events: none;` for elements with `nv-axis` class.

[image]
This style disables click event handling, so you have to override it. You can achieve it with this code:

```
d3.select(node)
  .selectAll('.nv-x.nv-axis, .nv-x .nv-axis')
  .style('pointer-events', 'all');

d3.select(node)
  .selectAll('.nv-x .tick')
  .on('click', function() {
    /* ... */
  });
```

Check [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmq98h8g/32/).